# best way for deploying a large javaee jsf application as a portlet

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, liferay, portlet

I am using liferay and glassfish application server to deploy my javaee jsf application as a portlet
If having a small application about 5 mb the deploy is almost good which take time as 10 sec for building the war file and 10 seconds for deploying the war file
My problem is that i have a large application which is about 100 mb which takes time 40 seconds for building war files and minimum 2 min for deploying the war file
for making changes in my application and at every change deploy my application to see the result and test what i have done ,this is annoying and boring for waiting a long time
Any suggestion for a deploying or testing changes with a better time

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393509/why-we-use-jrebel

Comment: If you can write a useful test suite, with good coverage, then you may perhaps need to deploy your application less frequently as your tests will give you sufficient confidence that your change has worked without needing to eyeball it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically it is a bad smell if the size your portlets tend to be this large. Why building a monolithic portlet if you already have a web application for this? My suggestions:

- Create a light-weight portlet that acts as the front-end for your existing application, the interface to your end-users if you wish. This way, your web application can stay as-is, doing the real work in de backend.
- Is it possible to split the web application into its functional parts? E.g. a search screen, a filter, a detail view, ... If that's the case, it might be possible to split your application into multiple portlets, working together to get the job done. This way, you add the flexibility of moving the portlets around on the page.

If you have no other option but to deploy the web application as a whole, make sure that the different parts of your application are modular enough to be tested on their own (see Mark Chorley's comment).